# sign Bound Field format

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to show negative Balance(-$400) with $ sign in Bound field in grid view.

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Balance" HeaderText="Balance"  ReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: Well do you have it as a negative value ? if your culture supports `$` then you can used `c` (currency formatting)

Answer (score 0):

i have done this like this

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Balance" DataFormatString = "{0:$,0}"  HeaderText="Balance"  ReadOnly="True" />
```